# Rails 3.2.1 JQuery Popup modal form - where do I put everything?

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, popup

There are many questions on StackOverflow regarding similar topic. In fact, I've already managed to get a basic dialog to popup in one of my controllers (which is part of a Model).

However, I seem to have problems to get Ajax popup form to work when I try to fire it from a controller (i.e. one that is NOT part of a Model).

I have a view called main\display.html.erb. A snippet of the code is shown below. It basically has a collection of @photos which I'm rendering in a partial.

```
    <%= render :partial => 'photo', :collection => @photos %>
```

The partial main\ _photo.html.erb looks like this (just a snippet):

```
    <td>
        <%= photo.title %><br>
        <%= image_tag(photo.url) %><br>
        <div id='media-form' title='Add Item to Selected Trip and Trip Item' >
            <%= render :partial => 'modal', locals: {photo: photo} %>
        </div>
    </td>
```

I'm already anticipating criticism on a partial within a partial (but not exactly sure why that's bad)...but heck, it works.

The partial form within the partial 'photo' (above) is main\ _modal.html.erb looks something like this:

```
    <%= form_tag({:controller => 'media', :action => 'create'}, :method => 'post' do  %>    
        <%= label_tag(:mi_id, 'Enter Media Item ID:') %>
        <%= text_field_tag(:mi_id) %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :url, photo.url %>
        <%= submit_tag('Add to Album')   %>
    <% end %>
```

I obviously then have a Model called 'Media' which has an action 'create' than would add the photo url into the database.

None of the above has any ajax or JQuery at the moment. I've played around with it before but none of it works. Ideally, I want to have a button (or link) in the partial main\ _photo.html.erb which would trigger the modal form as a popup...the modal form would be the one in main\ _modal.html.erb. The form would then have allow me to added data to the Media Model. Once added, the popup form closes and stay on the original main\display.html.erb page which has all the search results of photos without refreshing the page.

My main confusions are:
1) where should I put the .js.erb file which contains all the jQuery stuff? In the views\main folder or the views\media folder? Or neither?

2) If I want to have a button (or link) to trigger the popup form, do I need to create an action in the 'main' controller? Is this where I put the 'format.js' code to trigger the javascript? I've tried that already and Rails seems to have a problem recognising the 'format.js' when I use it in a Controller which is not part of a Model.

3) Where should the ':remote => true' go? Should it be in the button which triggers the form or should it be in the form or both?

4) If someone can show me some basic code on to get a basic popup form up and running in the .js.erb file then that would be much appreciated.

5) More of a general question - when is it good practice to put the javascript in application.js?

I'm sure you can tell from my question that I'm not really much of a coder and new to the ajax world but everyone's gotta start somewhere, right? :)